# No results with QXmlQuery

Tags: qt, xquery

I'm getting really fustrated with this...

With this simple xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<root>
   <data>hello</data>
</root>
```

And this code

```
QXmlQuery xquery;
xquery.setQuery( "doc('config.xml')//data" );

if( xquery.isValid() )
{
    QXmlResultItems itemResult;
 xquery.evaluateTo( &itemResult );
 QXmlItem item( itemResult.next() );
 while( !item.isNull() )
 {
  QVariant value = item.toAtomicValue();
  qDebug() << "One XML result!!!";
  item = itemResult.next();
 }
}
```

This code simply doesn't throw me any results.
I've checked that the execute path of app is the same where the config.xml is located.

Official documentation doesn't help me very much and seems there's no extra info on internet about details on how to use this class.

I have another program that successfully loads data from an xml and the code is exactly like the posted one. Even throws me an error if xml file is not found (a thing that with my current app doesn't happens).

Of course I'm configuring the .pro file to use xmlpatterns:

```
QT += xmlpatterns
```

Any clue??

Comment: I started a new project using QCreator 1.31 and using the same code now I receive from stdout messages complaining file not found when .xml is in root paht of the project. Complains dissapear and all working when placing .xml file in the build folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I remember I had some trouble with it as well... Anyway, I've found that I was using the following lines :

```
QFile SourceDocument;
SourceDocument.setFileName(rXmlFilePath);
...
Query.bindVariable("inputDocument", &SourceDocument);
QString FinalQuery("declare variable $inputDocument external;doc($inputDocument)//chapter");
Query.setQuery(FinalQuery);
```

I hope it will help you a bit !